# dyld: Symbol not found: _JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java, node.js, macos

What does this error mean?

What do I need to do to resolve it?

I'm trying to run a java based module for node.js (specifically, [xslt4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt4node)) on Mac OS El Captain but every time I get this error. Everything seems to work OK for windows users. The full error is below:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _JNI_CreateJavaVM 
>   Referenced from:
>   /projects/main-project/node_modules/java/build/Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _JNI_CreateJavaVM   Referenced from:
>   /projects/main-project/node_modules/java/build/Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
>   Expected in: flat namespace

I found [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: JNI_CreateJavaVM OS-X Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397076/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-jni-createjavavm-os-x-xcode) which is the closest I could find that explains my exact problem, but I'm not using xcode for development, I'm on a node.js platform.

Has anyone else seen this before? What does it mean?

**So far I have tried:**

1. Changing Java versions
2. Deleting and rebuilding `node_moudles`
3. Adding JVM capabilities `<string>JNI</string>`
4. Uninstalling Java, per documentation here: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml running those commands does nothing:

> user:~ kawnah$ sudo rm -fr
>   /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane user:~ kawnah$
>   sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java user:~ kawnah$
>   java -version java version "9.0.1" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (build 9.0.1+11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11,
>   mixed mode)

5. Trying different version of node (7.10.0)
6. Completely uninstalling node/npm, and reinstalling

Comment: `dyld` is the dynamic linking utility in mac osx, `JNI` is a java technology that allows java to interact with native applications.
The error means it can't find this function from `JNI` interface .. 
So it may be a clue for you to search. as I have no mac to dig deep

Comment: How are you linking node-java? with flags or extension in a setup file?

Comment: Have you updated node-java or node.js on the system? Maybe try a different version of node. If you do change versions you may still want to remove node_modules and reinstall. And you may want to try to uninstall node-java completely then do a clean install.

Comment: I did try a different version with same results (specifically 7.10.0 - *which is the version that works for everyone else*)I've done multiple clean wipes with different versions of java and node and nothing is working.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I FINALLY figured it out!

I needed this npm package for node-java to work properly on my machine https://www.npmjs.com/package/winreg

`npm install winreg` resolved all issues

Comment: winreg on Mac,really ?

Comment: Having the same issue, tried it just for giggles. As expected, it doesn't work.

Comment: dang. yeah this was from 3 years ago, I think part of it was an operating system problem, whats your rig?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what this error is telling you is that there's an issue with a symbolic link to a file in this module you're trying to use.

[Mac OS X's DYLD](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) is the OS's [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker). Its job is, more or less, to load shared libraries for the OS when resources are requested.

There are a number of reasons this could happen, from a failed update process on the module itself to drive corruption, etc.

The most common fix (1) to this specific issue is to delete your node_modules folder and run a fresh NPM install in both the local and global directories:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

You could alternatively attempt a npm rebuild, but a clean install is generally the best route to go.

---

1. from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130692/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-node-module-register)

Comment: I tried this already. I'm going to update my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually enable JNI by editing `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<version>.jdk/Contents/Info.plist` and adding JNI as an option in JVMCapabilities:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
<array>
    ...
    <string>JNI</string>
</array>
```

As found in https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/223#issuecomment-110408072

Comment: what happens if you open node and run this:
`var java = require('java');`
`var javaLangSystem = java.import('java.lang.System');`
`javaLangSystem.out.printlnSync('Hello World');`
?

Comment: `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _JNI_CreateJavaVM
  Referenced from: /projects/new-platform-prototype/node_modules/java/build/Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _JNI_CreateJavaVM
  Referenced from: /projects/new-platform-prototype/node_modules/java/build/Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: Have you tried installing this? https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
I have it installed.

Comment: Yes, it did not work either. I've done multiple clean wipes and re-installs of both node and java

Answer (score 0):

Try an `xcode-select --install` and then `npm rebuild`
Check [this](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3744) thread, problem seems to be apple's xcode (in your case it could be the c++ compiler),discussion is for ruby vm but might be similar for jvm.

Generally check/update your c++/c compiler and then try anything else ,like choosing another java version and adding JNI to capabilities. Last thing to mention node-gyp needs python version 2.x as mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) of node-java.

Comment: No go. Running that gave me `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates` So I did a software update and it did not fix the issue.