# npm install throws npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, macos

I upgraded node to 8.6.4 - after I did that I got the error. So I switched back to 8.6.0 using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This was in attempt to solve another problem I'm having which can be seen here: [dyld: Symbol not found: _JNI_CreateJavaVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927707/dyld-symbol-not-found-jni-createjavavm)

This is my full stack trace below:

> macbook-pro:project-dir kawnah$ npm i WARN registry
>   Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous
>   Warning EINTEGRITY:
>   sha512-mjGanIiwQJskCC18rPR6OmrZ6fm2Lc7PeGFYwCmy5J34wC6F1PzdGL6xeMfmgicfYcNLGuVFA3WzXtIDCQSZxQ==
>   integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted
>   sha512-mjGanIiwQJskCC18rPR6OmrZ6fm2Lc7PeGFYwCmy5J34wC6F1PzdGL6xeMfmgicfYcNLGuVFA3WzXtIDCQSZxQ==
>   but got sha1-wSYRB66y8pTr/+ye2eytUppgl+0=. (8793 bytes) WARN registry
>   Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a
>   request error during revalidation. WARN registry Unexpected warning
>   for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY:
>   sha512-NcdALwpXkTm5Zvvbk7owOUSvVvBKDgKP5/ewfXEznmQFfs4ZRmanOeKBTjRVjka3QFoN6XJ+9F3USqfHqTaU5w==
>   integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted
>   sha512-NcdALwpXkTm5Zvvbk7owOUSvVvBKDgKP5/ewfXEznmQFfs4ZRmanOeKBTjRVjka3QFoN6XJ+9F3USqfHqTaU5w==
>   but got sha1-76ouqdqg16suoTqXsritUf776L4=. (2394 bytes) WARN registry
>   Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a
>   request error during revalidation. npm WARN babel-loader@6.4.1
>   requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/kawnah/.npm/_logs/2018-01-04T19_46_31_194Z-debug.log

This github thread: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858 suggests it's just a bug with NPM itself. That's not my problem, as it was working perfectly fine.

How do I resolve this?

EDIT: Upon further inspection, all my node modules installed successfully. But that still doesn't tell me what the error means?

Comment: Try rolling back your version of `npm`. What version are you using now?

Comment: it is npm -v
5.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had luck by downgrading to npm 5.2.0

```
npm install -g npm@5.2.0
```

Comment: 5.6.0 was working perfectly fine, it's so strange that it all of the sudden just breaks...